# delete particular string values in the column

Tags: string, pandas, dataframe

I have column which contains 4000 unique values(rows). I want to delete values such as 'I__ND_LD(1),I__ND_LD(2),P__ND_LN(1),I__XF_XF(4)'.these values are unique in numbers in the brackets. for example. 'I__ND_LD(1) starts with 1 and end with 'I__ND_LD(70).

By this code,I can remove only one character using above function. I want to remove all the values as mentioned in the problem.

```
eda[~eda.Devices.str.Contains("^I__ND_LD(1)")]
```

Is there any other technique through which i can remove all these values, also we have different number of 'I__ND_LD' and 'P__ND_LN(1). I want to implement this in the function so that I can just pass the values and it delete all the values in the column.

Answer (score 1):

```
to_remove = ['abc\(\d+\)', 'bca']
eda[~eda.devices.str.contains('|'.join(to_remove), regex=True)]
```

Comment: I can remove single value using this. i have like abc(1),abc(2) tilll abc(70) and something like withe bca as well.

Comment: Use regex in the list, something like the updated answer @anmol

Comment: It would be specific in your case and I can't tell you directly. If you need regex assistance the check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean).